# jQuery AJAX or XHR request trigger fail callbacks from done callback

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in my done handler of a jQuery XHR (created from a $.get() call) to look for problems in the response and then trigger the registered subsequent handlers (lie fail & always) with a custom error message?

something like this:

```
$.get( URL )
.done(
    function (data, status, res) {
    if(/*some condition*/){
            this.Reject(res, status, "some reason");
            return    
        }
    //Do stuff on success
    }
)

.fail(
//Common error handler here
)
.always(
    //common always handler here
);
```

Kind of a secondary filter on done.  The reason is of course all the APIs that shove an error in a 200 response that jQuery could never know was an error.

Comment: No there is not! The fail method executes when something fails during the ajax call. Errors on the serverside that will still pass a valid response it not considered an error. If your serverside code fails you can trigger the fail method by passing invalid content or a 400 header or anything else really that would trigger the fail method, but you can not call it from within the done method, and it's not really the appropriate thing to do either.

Comment: how is it not appropriate?  It's rather common for a futures/promise/task to be able to trigger the error callbacks.

Comment: Yes, but if you create a promise it can be rejected to trigger the fail method, in an ajax call the fail method lets you know that something went wrong with the call itself, while any valid response from the server is a successful ajax call. Any errors happening on the serverside failing to ouput whatever you expected should be caught in the success handler. Or at least that's the way it's normally done as you can't trigger the fail method from the done method as the promise has already been resolved by that time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do this, and it works nicely:

```
$.get( URL )
.then(
    function (data, status, res) {
        if(/**some error check**/({
             return $.Deferred().reject(res, status, "error message");
        }

        return $.Deferred().resolve(data, status, res);
    }
)
.done(
    function (data, status, res) {
        //Do stuff on success
    }
)

.fail(
//Common error handler here
)
.always(
    //common always handler here
);
```

works like a charm, now i don't have messy data error handling in my done, i can just focus on processing data or setting error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question, and Chris's answer.

I tried this and it worked, except it was triggering the fail function for an implicit unexpected exception (caused by a bug), not for my test AJAX exception. Which made me thought, it might work for an explicit exception without the hassle of creating a new promise object. So I though I would try an explicit throw - and it worked.

This explicit throwing works in jQuery 3. I'm not sure about earlier versions. I tried doing this in a `done` handler and it didn't work: throwing only seems to work in a `then` handler

```
$.get( URL )
.then(
    function (data, status, res) {
        if(/**some error check**/({
             throw "error message";
        }

        return data; //this is also important
    }
)
.done(
    function (data, status, res) {
        //Do stuff on success
    }
)

.fail(
//Common error handler here
)
.always(
    //common always handler here
);
```