# jQuery deferred: throw and catch an exception in the fail() callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am trying to make an ajax request and throw an exception when it fails. Unfortunately I am not able to catch the exception. My code looks like this:

```
try {
    jQuery.ajax('http://www.someurlthatwillproduceanerror.com')
        .fail(function () {
            throw 'an exception';
        })
        .done(function () {
            console.log('ok');
        })
    ;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I would expect the code to catch the exception and log 'an exception' to the console. Instead I end up with an uncaught exception.

Does anyone know how to handle exceptions in this case?

Comment: sorry... it won't work like that because you are dealing with asynchronous execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. That's not how exception handling works with promises.

The code inside the `done` clause is not executed in the same time or context as the try/catch. You can't asynchronously catch exceptions like that (yet!) in the browser.

My suggestion is **treat** the `.fail` clause *as the catch*.

```
jQuery.ajax('http://www.someurlthatwillproduceanerror.com')
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("an exception"); // the handler here!
    })
    .done(function () {
        console.log('ok');
    });
```

Note that the code that does something based on the exception does not have to be in the same place as the code declaring the promise.

```
var p = jQuery.ajax('http://www.someurlthatwillproduceanerror.com');
... 
...
p.fail(function(){ /* I'm handling it here */}); // .catch in modern promise libs
```

In general, it might be a good idea to return the promise from functions that deal with promises - that usually produces cleaner code.

Comment: "That's not how exception handling works with promises" - that is an overly broad statement. That's merely how "jQuery exception handling" works. ECMAScript promises allow bubbling from handler to handler, which allow generic catch handlers, as well as downstream handlers.

Comment: @Todd no it's not, this is about bubbling to _synchronous_ code outside the promise chain - this can't work because the promise code runs asynchronously. This is simply not how the language works - you can use an async function which lets you `await` things - but that's changing the rules :)

Comment: This is not about bubbling to synchronous code as you have just said. Read his first sentence. His code is an example of what the answer might look like, it doesn't constrain the answer to require synchronous blocking. Your answer doesn't relate to a synchronous catch block either. See my answer below to see what I meant, and is a very good candidate for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `fail` function you provide that throws the exception is executed asynchronously.

I'm assuming you wanted to propagate up an error to the caller, so given that, you should know that deferred failure is designed to model this by definition (propagating up a failure, except one that occurs asynchronously).

You should return the deferred promise to the caller and the caller can then attach its own success/fail callbacks instead of relying on try/catch. Here's sample generic Deferred use:

```
function yourFunc() {
    return jQuery.ajax('http://www.someurlthatwillproduceanerror.com')
        .done(function () {
            console.log('ok');
        });
}

yourFunc().fail(function() { console.log('this... instead of a try/catch.'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're trying to put all your error-handling code in one place. If so, you can take advantage of the fact that jQuery's [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method (or [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or whatever) implements the [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) interface, and put any risky code in a [then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) function.

Here's how:

```
jQuery.ajax('http://www.someurlthatwillproduceanerror.com/but/only/maybe')

  .then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // This function handles the response. It is NOT called if the AJAX fails.
    console.log('ok');

    /** An optional result object to pass to your done() function */
    var result;

    try {
      // Code that might blow up goes here
      result = 'The final result';
    } catch (e) {
      // Oh no—it blew up!
      // Reject the promise with the function signature of an AJAX failure
      return $.Deferred().reject(jqXHR, textStatus, e);
    }

    // We only get this far if there wasn't an exception.
    return result; // Optional
  })

  .done(function(result) {
    // This function gets called if there were no problems at all.
    alert('Well, that\'s just ducky! Contact the vendor ' +
        'and tell them to promote their devs!');
    console.log('Woo-hoo!', result);
  })

  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // This function gets called if the AJAX failed, or if there was an exception
    alert('Something went wrong. Contact the vendor ' +
        'and tell them to give their devs more money!');
    console.error('Rats!', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
  });
```

This way, you have one fail() function for any unexpected error, whether it's on the server side or client side.

Comment: Unexplained down-votes are the unannotated one-star app ratings of the StackExchange world.

Comment: Up you go then. Actually, in jQuery 3 (at least) you can just throw an exception from within a THEN handler, and it will bubble down. I tried the method here (and referring to your comment link) and it worked, except it worked for a naturally occurring exception, which made me think it might work for an explicitly thrown exception - and it worked: but only in a THEN handler. see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44948690/887092